# Django - include template tags

Tags: django, templates, templatetags

Currently I'm using a template which I include in my main template to display a form and submit it back. Problem is that none of the submit buttons work inside that template but only if they are placed inside the main template.

My code is:

```
  {% csrf_token %}
{{ exampleForm.management_form }}
  {% for form in exampleForm %}
  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="GET" class="exaSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="example1" type="hidden">
      {{ exampleForm.management_form }}
        ( {{ form.letterOfWord }} + {{ form.keyToUse }} ) MOD 26 =
          {{ form.letterToFill }} <button name="action" class="validateButton" value="validate"> Validate </button>  <br>
        </div>
      </form>
  {% endfor %}
```

The validate button does not do anything. It only works when I call it in the main template and not from inside the include template. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
  {% csrf_token %}
{{ exampleForm.management_form }}
  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="GET" class="exaSubmit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% for form in exampleForm %}
    <div id="example1" type="hidden">
      {{ exampleForm.management_form }}
        ( {{ form.letterOfWord }} + {{ form.keyToUse }} ) MOD 26 =
          {{ form.letterToFill }} <br>
        </div>

  {% endfor %}
<button name="action" class="validateButton" value="validate"> Validate     </button> 
</form>
```

Comment: But if I wanted it to generate a button for each form? How could I do that?

Comment: Have you created at list of forms which is assigned to exampleForm? Because, in your loop you are iterating over whole form.

Comment: Can we go into a chat room please so I can explain you what I'm doing? Its kind of long.

Comment: Yeah. Sure. Count me in

Comment: Never mind, here is the chat [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101281/django-formsets)